# What is the verb form of "quilt"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I was asked by my teacher to turn *quilt* into a verb.

I don't see the corresponding verb in the Oxford Dictionary.

Comment: It's in [at least one online Oxford dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/quilt).

Comment: My guess is that you wrote a sentence in which "quilt" appears as a noun, and your teacher wants you to rearrange the sentence so that quilt becomes a verb. I'd have to see the sentence to be able to tell you what changes are involved, but if you had written "The women were busy working on a quilt all afternoon," you could rephrase it as "The women busily quilted all afternoon."

Answer (score 2):

The verb form is the same: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quilt so to me it seems like a strange question from your teacher.

Comment: Yes,but i am orderd to change it from noun to verb,then,what would i write?

Comment: The verb form of the noun _quilt_ is **to quilt**.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like the teacher involved would want that answer. I'd require: The verb form of the noun _quilt_ is (also) **quilt**. (The base form of the verb is _quilt_; _to quilt_ is the to-infinitive, not the base form (though the to-infinitive often occurs in writing and speech, of course - even in the dictionary definitions). Most dictionaries now sensibly list the base form as a headword. Ask the teacher to check in a modern online dictionary, not 1983 Chambers.)

Comment: You could also provide an example: "the archers spotted the assassin sneaking in and quilted him with arrows".

Comment: Yes, as others have commented, you need to just answer that it is the same. It could almost be called a "trick question", I would say.